# Can I retrieve realtime logs from AWS CloudWatch using AWS SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-sdk-nodejs

The closest thing I could find is [getLogEvents](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudWatchLogs.html#getLogEvents-property) but in order to display log in real time, I had to continuously call [getLogEvents](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudWatchLogs.html#getLogEvents-property), which is not good.

Is there anyway I can do something like this?

```
cloudwatchlogs.getLogStream(params, function(err, stream) {
  stream.on('newlog', logs => {
    console.log(logs);
  });
});
```

Comment: check kineses  .

Answer (score 2):

Instead of polling for Logs manually you can do one of the following.

- Setup AWS Kinesis to stream your Logs and process them individually or batches using Lambda. For more details check the [Example 1: Subscription Filters with Kinesis](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html).
- Setup a Lambda to be triggered based on CloudWatch events when a new log is available. For more details check the [Example 2: Subscription Filters with AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html).

Note: If you need to receive the update locally, in your NodeJS App listen to a websocket using [AWS IOT](https://medium.com/@jparreira/receiving-aws-iot-messages-in-your-browser-using-websockets-9b87f28c2357). From the AWS Cloud Watch trigger using Lambda, push the data to the IOT Topic which will be received by your NodeJS App in near realtime.

Comment: I'm not clearly understand how AWS Kinesis works. Can this be done locally on my machine? I just want to stream the output to my console programmatically with Node.js.

Comment: You cannot run this locally. Both options requires to run in AWS.

Comment: So there is currently not possible handle stuffs like notifying / streaming / receive events from AWS with SDK? That's sad.

Comment: There is a way of doing it. In your NodeJS app listen to a websocket using AWS IOT. From the AWS Cloud Watch trigger using Lambda, push the data to the IOT socket which will be received by your NodeJS app near realtime.

Answer (score 2):

See: [Real-time Processing of CloudWatch Log Data with Subscriptions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/Subscriptions.html)

Three examples are given on how to use the subscription filters:

[Using CloudWatch Logs Subscription Filters](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html)

Comment: I'm looking for a solution I can use locally in my machine. Is that possible?

Comment: @TrungDQ Sorry, I didn't see the AWS SDK part. I do not think it is possible to it with SDK without calling it continuously.